# Can modern residual stress measurement replace finite element calculation?

Tags: stresses, finite-element-method, experimental-physics

Residual stresses are created by the manufacturing process and exist in materials and structures. Now, people develop many methods to measure residual stresses. Those methods can be divided into destructive methods and non-destructive methods. It seems that with the emergence of the non-destructive method, the finite element has no advantage. For example, X-ray Diffraction is attached to a strict formula: Bragg formula. This leads me to a question, Is it still necessary to obtain residual stress by the finite element method?

The following is the Experimental procedure:

For each structuring element, we irradiate this structuring element several times with an X-ray of wavelength λ at different incident angles. We measure the corresponding diffraction angle 2θ, then the slope M from 2θ to sin^2 ψ can be calculated, then the stress σ can be calculated.

[image]

Comment: How do you propose to take the measurement, on every structural element? I don't understand how it can replace the FEM analysis, please elaborate further.

Comment: @r13 Sure, I add the experiment detail. It is based on X-ray Diffraction method which use Bragg's law.

Comment: It seems quite promising for investigation on the existing structures, for which the exact state of the material is difficult to evaluate. However, I don't think it can replace FEM in the design stage, which is purported to find the most critical stresses and perform optimization efficiently before the structure is ever constructed.

Comment: @r13 I got it. Prediction is one of the advantages of the finite element method over experiments.